# Dynamic classes: are they prepended or appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My question is a very general one:
When dynamic classes are added to an element(for example through any of jQuery-ui's add-ons),
and there are already classes on that element, is the dynamically added class appended or prepended to the list of classes?

Why Question is based on the following:
I am trying to select all elements with a dymanic class starting with an identifier (ex. title_ ) so I simply write $('[class^title_]').

My concern is the possibility of another developer coming along and adding a $.datepicker (for example) to that element thereby adding another class/es to that element and if those classes get prepended to the element - [there goes my selector](http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/get-the-class-that-starts-with-tp81353p81355.html)

Thanks in advance

Here's my situation: Showing the coldfusion cfloop creating the checkboxes:

```
    <cfset lbls = {"test1" = "Test one","test2" = "Test two","test3" = "Test three","test4" = "Test four","test5" = "Test five"}>
    <cfloop collection=#lbls# item="num">
      <cfoutput>
        <tr>
          <td><label>#lbls['#num#']#</label>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form_test test_#num#" value="#num#" name="test_yes" ></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form_test test_#num#" value="#num#" name="test_no" ></td>
        </tr>
     </cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
```

I would am creating dynamic checkboxes (yes or no )for 5 categories dynamically ( looping over a coldfusion list to create them) [ they're not radio boxes to allow the user to uncheck all]. SO how would I reference the "other" checkbox?
I can't use siblings() since they're in seperate td's . I could go to the parent and select parents('th').children(':checkbox').not(this) but I was hoping for a shorter way.

Comment: Your selector looks like a hack rather than proper practice. And the fact you need to do such selection probably means you have a design problem.

Comment: @dystroy I appreciate being critiqued but can you advise on a better selector option.

Comment: Alnitak did. But not knowing the complete problem, I can hardly give a solution. Distinct classes come to mind (`$('.title_a, .title_b, .title_c')`) which would be more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're appended, but you shouldn't rely on it.

A better fix is to attach both a generic identifying class, and a more specific class:

```
<elem class="title title_foo"> ... </elem>
```

and then select for the former using a minimal class selector if you want all such elements:

```
$('.title')
```

This will be *way* more efficient and reliable than using attribute matching selectors.

Comment: voted on for answering the Question, but I don't think your advice is applicable to my situation. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Rob please feel free to go into why this might not apply.  As dystroy said, resorting to relying on the order of entries in a class attribute sounds like a design problem.

Comment: I didn't want to bother, but since you asked :) I'm adding it to my above question

Comment: @Rob I would go for something like `$('.check').not(this)` (if `check` is the class that exists on all of them)